# how to to get first top 6 records indifferent columns T-sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got a situation to display first top 6 records. first 3 records in `FirstCol` and next 3 in `SecondCol`. My query is like this:

```
select top 6 [EmpName] 
from [Emp ]
order by [Salary] Desc
```

Result:

```
[EmpName]
----------------------
Sam           
Pam           
Oliver        
Jam
Kim
Nixon
```

But I want the result to look like this:

```
FirstCol      SecondCol
Sam           Jam
Pam           Kim
Oliver        Nixon
```

Comment: why not just format the results like this on the UI?  Why do they need to be returned like this from the DB?

Comment: Formatting it in this way through SQL Server could possible make Server working much slower. As @Kritner said, get it normally into UI and than format it as you would like to look. Much better, much faster, must easier.

Comment: Hi Kritner, it's our requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using several windowing functions, this is kind of ugly but it will get you the result that you want:

```
;with data as
(
  -- get your Top 6
  select top 6 empname, salary
  from emp
  order by salary desc
), 
buckets as
(
  -- use NTILE to split the six rows into 2 buckets
  select empname, 
    nt = ntile(2) over(order by salary desc),
    salary
  from data
) 
select 
  FirstCol = max(case when nt = 1 then empname end),
  SecondCol = max(case when nt = 2 then empname end) 
from
(
  -- create a row number for each item in the buckets to return multiple rows
  select empname,
    nt,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by nt order by salary desc)
  from buckets
) d
group by rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f170b/8).  This uses the function [`NTILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx), this takes your dataset of six rows and splits it into two buckets - 3 rows in bucket 1 and 3 rows in bucket 2.  The `(2)` inside the `NTILE` is used to determine the number of buckets.

Next I used `row_number()` to create a unique value for each row within each bucket, this allows you to return multiple rows for each column.

Answer (score 2):

```
; WITH TOP_3 AS 
 (
  select TOP  3 [EmpName] 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Salary] Desc) rn 
  from [Emp ]
  order by [Salary] Desc
  ),
  Other3 AS
 (
    SELECT [EmpName] 
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Salary] Desc) rn 
    FROM Employees 
    ORDER BY [Salary] DESC OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
 )
SELECT T3.[EmpName] , O3.[EmpName]
FROM TOP_3 T3 INNER JOIN Other3 O3
ON T3.RN = O3.RN 
ORDER BY T3.RN ASC
```

Comment: This is a solution for your answer, but definitely not the best one. Read comments from me and @Kritner and better do it in that way.  VOTE for answer anyway.

Comment: Hi M.Ali, thanks for the reply, but my serer is not 2012 version. its 2008 can you suggest any other alternate. thanks

Comment: Why you have SQL Server 2012 tagged in your question then ?

Comment: just deleted 2012 tag